# Trying to convert from C# to VB.net

Tags: c#, vb.net

I am trying to change this C# code to VB.net and am running into an issue with the username select box not populating with the list of membership users. The C# code properly displays the users list.

C#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class admin_change_change : System.Web.UI.Page
{

MembershipUserCollection users;

protected void Page_LoadComplete(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    users = Membership.GetAllUsers();

    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        UserName.DataSource = users;
        UserName.DataBind();
    }
}

protected void btnChange_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MembershipUser userToChange = Membership.GetUser(UserName.SelectedItem.Value);

    if (userToChange != null)
    {
        userToChange.ChangePassword(userToChange.ResetPassword(), NewPassword.Text);
        Response.Redirect("/admin/");
    }
    else
    {
        message.Text = "Invalid Username or Password";
    }
}

protected void btnGoBack_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect("/admin/");
}

}
```

VB.NET

```
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Linq
Imports System.Web
Imports System.Web.Security
Imports System.Web.UI
Imports System.Web.UI.WebControls

Public Partial Class admin_change_change
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Private users As MembershipUserCollection

Protected Sub Page_LoadComplete(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    users = Membership.GetAllUsers()

    If Not IsPostBack Then
        UserName.DataSource = users
        UserName.DataBind()
    End If
End Sub

Protected Sub btnChange_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim userToChange As MembershipUser = Membership.GetUser(UserName.SelectedItem.Value)

    If userToChange IsNot Nothing Then
        userToChange.ChangePassword(userToChange.ResetPassword(), NewPassword.Text)
        Response.Redirect("/admin/")
    Else
        message.Text = "Invalid Username or Password"
    End If
End Sub

Protected Sub btnGoBack_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Response.Redirect("/admin/")
End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: You got it .. it wasn't. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your event handler is missing the `Handles Me.LoadComplete` at the end of it:

```
Protected Sub Page_LoadComplete(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.LoadComplete
    users = Membership.GetAllUsers()

    If Not IsPostBack Then
        UserName.DataSource = users
        UserName.DataBind()
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

By default, [AutoEventWireup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.pagessection.autoeventwireup%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is false in ASP.Net VB. As the result, you need to explicity attach the event like roryap suggested.

```
<%@ Page AutoEventWireup="false" %>
```

However, if you do not want to attach manually, you can make `AutoEventWireup="true"` which is default in ASP.net C#.

Make sure **Page_LoadComplete** should be renamed to **Page_Load** which is a stand event name.

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    If Not IsPostBack Then
        Dim users = Membership.GetAllUsers()
        UserName.DataSource = users
        UserName.DataBind()
    End If
End Sub
```

In addition, **users** should be inside **if statement** if its value is not used in the rest of the page to avoid unnecessary data retrieving from DataBase.

[Here](http://converter.telerik.com/) is the free VB to C# code converter.